# CUDA dynamic parallelism: Access child kernel results in global memory

Tags: memory-management, cuda, dynamic-parallelism

I am currently trying my first dynamic parallelism code in CUDA. It is pretty simple. In the parent kernel I am doing something like this:

```
int aPayloads[32];
// Compute aPayloads start values here

int* aGlobalPayloads = nullptr;
cudaMalloc(&aGlobalPayloads, (sizeof(int) *32));
cudaMemcpyAsync(aGlobalPayloads, aPayloads, (sizeof(int)*32), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));

mykernel<<<1, 1>>>(aGlobalPayloads); // Modifies data in aGlobalPayloads
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

// Access results in payload array here
```

Assuming that I do things right so far, what is the fastest way to access the results in `aGlobalPayloads` after kernel execution? (I tried `cudaMemcpy()` to copy `aGlobalPayloads` back to `aPayloads` but `cudaMemcpy()` is not allowed in device code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can directly access the data in `aGlobalPayloads` from your parent kernel code, without any copying:

   ```
   mykernel<<<1, 1>>>(aGlobalPayloads); // Modifies data in aGlobalPayloads
   cudaDeviceSynchronize();
   int myval = aGlobalPayloads[0];
   ```
2. I'd encourage careful error checking  (Read the whole accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api)).  You do it in device code the same way as in host code. The [programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#api-reference) states: "May not pass in local or shared memory pointers".  Your usage of `aPayloads` is a local memory pointer.
3. If for some reason you want that data to be explicitly put back in your local array, you can use in-kernel `memcpy` for that:

   ```
   memcpy(aPayloads, aGlobalPayloads, sizeof(int)*32);
   int myval = aPayloads[0]; // retrieves the same value
   ```

   (that is also how I would fix the issue I mention in item 2 - use in-kernel `memcpy`)

Comment: Thanks a lot! In the actual code of course I will do full error checking. Should I expect a performance difference between accessing aGlobalPayloads int-by-int vs copying them to local memory en bloc and accessing aPayloads int-by-int? (I would expect a burst transfer to be more efficient but I don't know much about device-internal memory transfers)

Comment: I would expect the access to `aGlobalPayloads` to be faster than copying it to local memory first, but really that's just a guess.  If this is very important to you, then you may wish to do some micro-benchmarking.  The copy operation is not a "burst transfer" whatever that means.  It is a loop, just like you would write, that copies things byte-by-byte.  Direct access should be quicker than that byte-by-byte copy, followed by local access.

Comment: Well, burst transfer or burst mode describes the situation where a data transfer duration consists of an per-transfer-penalty and a penalty per byte. Such transfers tend to be much faster when transfering bigger portions of data. A lot of architectures and protocols have burst transfers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burst_mode_(computing)